# webpack transpiling using --watch and setting up react files

Tags: javascript, webpack, docker-compose

So I am using the following [tutorial](http://dapperdeveloper.com/2016/05/18/developing-with-docker-and-webpack/). I can access the localhost, but I am putting in an html file. The tutorial does not go into depth about setting up a javascript file and getting that file to transpile. Can someone help me with the setup. I have googled this topic and I keep coming across tutorials that talk about needing babel for the transpiling, yet the tutorial says

> Now that everything’s ready to go, we can get webpack to watch for
>   code changes in our directory and transpile.

But I feel like this means it should just bundle up everything in my project since webpack is a bundling product. Further, I am confused by the call to webpack:

```
CMD webpack --watch --watch-polling
```

Does this mean I don't need to put in an entry point and endpoint? I thought with webpack I need to provide those two details, but the tutorial again is calling directly to just polling.

Thanks in advance for any help getting my structure setup so I can run webpack, react in docker.

In terms of setting up the files, I had to add

```
COPY wwwroot ./wwwroot
```

Just to get the project to display something at localhost. But I want files to be brought over automatically if possible. But I am not sure of the intent of the tutorial with regards to file structure.

Comment: So you want webpack watch to be running at one place also serve the project using some other command?

Comment: @Tarun, yes basically. The tutorial sounded like a good way to have a production ready server through nginx that I could control, have a docker container hold it all together and still be able to edit code locally through the use of code watching. But I want to make sure i have all the moving parts - I think the tutorial is leaving some details out, most notably babel and the jsx files.